# Is there a formula to change the value of a call, depending on selection from drop down list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a prices spredsheet.

I need one column where you can choose a product from a drop down list
The next column you enter the amount of units required
The next column (the tricky one) to calculate the price of the sum of the amount of units, however the cost of 1 unit is different for each product so this column would need to somehow know that product A costs x amount and times that but the amount of units needed.

is this possible?

Thanks
joe

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a column for the price per unit?

Answer (score 2):

Sure

Firstly, you will need a point of reference for your price list. So, a table containing the Item and prices (per unit or item etc)

You will need a drop down list (data validation) that references the items in your price list

Example:

```
=VLOOKUP("ITEM","ITEM_PRICE_LIST","COLUMN_WITH_PRICE",FALSE)
```

You then use simple math to multiply the vlookup result (ITEM PRICE) by the number of units!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you create a two column table of products and prices on a separate sheet (or even the same sheet) then you can use the excel function =vlookup to locate the price based on the item name.

Comment: Hi Tyson, What you are saying is exactly the solution. The last time is made an answer i was "down voted" saying "superuser guide" says answers have to be in detail.... Just sharing a word of caution. If you can just illustrate your solution with an example.

Comment: While it is possible to create a detailed example there are many steps and conditions.  (how the table is arranged and optimized etc).  If the OP is sufficiently proficient to use drop lists in excel, then this particular question simply means the knowledge gap they are missing is what function to use to lookup the price (i.e. VLOOKUP)

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Your answer gives the right direction in which the user should proceed. I share the same opinion. I did something like this and got "downvoted" - I'm on the verge of 50reps - one more down vote means i will no longer be able to comment.. Per se, there are people who just post a question and never even return to check the answer (bad exp) coz of whom u get down voted... Good job Tyson..